# How to delete words between multiple parenthesis in pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to delete parenthesis and the words between them in pandas dataframe. So far I have searched and found this to be very helpful-

```
df['Column'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
```

But this converts the following string-

Lemon ( 20 % ... ), orange (...) and apple (...) done.

(... contain other letters)

to

Lemon done.

However, I want the output to be-

Lemon, orange and apple done.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask another question! Ask a new one, with the same rules like doing research, making attempts etc.

Comment: Also not to forget giving substantial info like DataFrame structure your have which you are looking the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Column'].str.replace(r"\((.*?)\)","")
```

**Output**

```
Lemon , orange  and apple  done.
```

**Explanation**

1. `\(` matches the character `(` literally (case sensitive)
2. `.*?`matches any character (except for line terminators)
3. `\)` matches the character `)` literally (case sensitive)

**P.S** - I have found [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to be a good online testing tools for regex (I am in no way associated with them).

**EDIT**

Adding a `+` might do it for the nested case (*not tested thoroughly*) -

```
\(+(.*?)\)+
```

FYI - Agreed with @Ulrich about asking a fresh question :-)

Comment: Sorry, It takes some time after someone answers to accept that answer. BTW, why is .*? is put inside parenthesis?

Comment: @sudddddd that is just the first capturing group to logically separate it

Comment: I don't get the explanation: There are two changes, one is that the `.*` that's supposed to match the content of the brackets is now `.*?` and the other is that the content is assigned to a group, so it could be referenced in the replacement part. None of these explain to me why this version works. My approach would have been `\([^(]*\)` btw.

Comment: Okay, just found the answer myself in the provided link: The `a*?` is documented as "Matches as few characters as possible", so that's the important difference.

Comment: Hi! And what about eliminate a space between a word previous the parenthesis? Ex: my expression is Aqua (xyz***) and I want to get just "Aqua" but I need it without the space between the word and the parenthesis.

Comment: @AdN14 just trim the string post getting rid of parenthesis/split the string by `" "`
 and then do a `" ".join()`

Comment: I was thinking and was just as simple as add `\s` in my Regexp before `\(`, thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Below method can help you:

`df['Column'].str.replace('\(.*?\)', '')`